# Help me save my database

Tags: mysql, innodb, cascading-deletes

I recently migrated my database to a different server.

On the old server I made heavy use of InnoDB's ON DELETE CASCADE rules.

On the new server, MySql did not have the InnoDB engine setup.

At the time of migration, the new server defauted to MyISAM - and I did not notice this until now.  (Knocking head against wall!)

So, here is the situation:  Because the database has been in use, some of my tables that used the ON DELETE CASCADE rule are now out of sync.  (Still knocking head against wall.)

This means I can't just change the tables over to InnoDB and reapply the cascade rules - some of the keys now reference rows that no longer exist.

My question is this:

Is there a way to configure an INSERT statement so that if any of the rows that are being inserted violate a cascade rule, it just silently ignores that row and moves onto the next?  (At first I thought INSERT IGNORE would accomplish this, but I have tried it and it does not seem to work.)

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: use "SET foreign_key_checks = 0" and try to move tables to innoDB. I have not tried but see if it works. take backup before doing anything ..

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1**

Make a backup

**STEP 2**

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;

Migrate your data

SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

**STEP 3**

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT foreign_key_id FROM table2);
```

Where the delete statements match your `ON DELETE CASCADE` rules.
Remember the order in which you do your deletes is important, so plan and make extra backups along the way if need be.

Once you are done backup one more time and edit the backup SQL statement so that the lines `SET foreign_key_checks = x` are **not** present.
If your backup with foreign key checks **enabled** works, you're back in business.

*I'm sure you can figure out more efficient delete queries without `IN`, just my 2 cents*